# Samba DNS records not found by bind

Tags: bind, samba4

OK, so I had a Samba server managing a windows domain set up and running for quite a time, but I re-installed bind recently and this seems to have broken DNS for Samba. I have the situation that a DNS query with samba-tool works, but using "host" or "nslookup" commands doesn't:

```
$ samba-tool dns query localhost sodrakalland.local debora A -U Administrator 
Password for [SODRAKALLAND\Administrator]:
  Name=, Records=1, Children=0
    A: 172.24.57.6 (flags=f0, serial=110, ttl=1200)

$ host debora
Host debora not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

$ nslookup debora
Server:         172.24.57.2
Address:        172.24.57.2#53

** server can't find debora: NXDOMAIN
```

Any ideas why this might be?

This is my dns config:

```
$ cat /etc/bind/named.conf
include "/usr/local/samba/share/setup/named.conf.dlz";

$ cat /usr/local/samba/share/setup/named.conf.dlz
dlz "AD DNS Zone" {
    database "dlopen /usr/local/samba/lib/bind9/dlz_bind9.so";
};
```

In the log.samba i get these errors from time to time, which I guess happen on incoming lookups in the network, but other than this, nothing special is logged:

```
[2017/07/31 13:22:52,  0] ../source4/dsdb/dns/dns_update.c:294(dnsupdate_nameupdate_done) ../source4/dsdb/dns/dns_update.c:294: Failed DNS update - NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT
```

### EDIT

I decided to go with Samba's built-in DNS server for now. However, [Patrick Mevzek](https://serverfault.com/users/396475/patrick-mevzek) provided [this guide](https://dev.tranquil.it/wiki/SAMBA_-_Integration_avec_bind9) for setting it up, and from reading it I highly suspect that my crucial mistake (or at least one of them) was to forget to add `server services = -dns` in the `[global]` section of `smb.conf`.

Comment: This guide is in French but seems useful and adds various steps needed such as permission changes and so : https://dev.tranquil.it/wiki/SAMBA_-_Integration_avec_bind9

Comment: Thank you! It looks very useful (once google translated it). I have however decided to go with samba's built-in dns server for now. Will update the post.